# Write a loop inside the echo bash-script

Tags: bash

I used bash script to generate input files for a program. The bash script generates the list of random numbers followed by the writing the input file. My bash script has two sections where first section generates the list of random numbers and second section use a random number to build the output file contents.

```
   # 1- Generate Random Numbers
    for i in {1..200}
    do
    ARRAY+=($((RANDOM%885+0)))
    done
    echo "
    ${ARRAY[*]}
    "> random_numbers.txt
# 2- construction of output file    
echo "
# Packmol input file
filetype pdb
output peg_$(($npeg)).pdb
# selecting the structure according random number
structure peg${ARRAY[0]}.pdb
  number 1
  inside cube -$d. -$d. -$d. $d.
end structure
structure peg${ARRAY[1]}.pdb
  number 1
  inside cube -$d. -$d. -$d. $d.
end structure
structure peg${ARRAY[2]}.pdb
  number 1
  inside cube -$d. -$d. -$d. $d.
end structure
structure peg${ARRAY[3]}.pdb
  number 1
  inside cube -$d. -$d. -$d. $d.
end structure
structure peg${ARRAY[4]}.pdb
  number 1
  inside cube -$d. -$d. -$d. $d.
end structure
continued *****
structure peg${ARRAY[24]}.pdb
  number 1
  inside cube -$d. -$d. -$d. $d.
end structure

"> output.inp
```

Is there a way if I can run a loop of different range (25, 50, 75 ...) over the repeating lines given below by changing the Array number?

```
structure peg${ARRAY[*]}.pdb
  number 1
  inside cube -$d. -$d. -$d. $d.
end structure
```

Comment: FYI, it would be better form to use lower-case characters for your variable names; all-uppercase names are conventionally reserved for environment variables and builtins.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to structure the loop inside the echo, rather than breaking up the `echo`, and putting its parts inside a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
  # write header
  printf '%s\n' '# Packmol input file' 'filetype pdb' "output peg_$((npeg)).pdb"

  # iterate over array contents
  for value in "${ARRAY[@]}"; do
    printf '%s\n' \
      "structure peg${value}" \
      '  number 1' \
      '  inside cube -$d. -$d. -$d. $d.' \
      'end structure'
  done
} >output.inp
```

---

...to take only every 25th item, modify the inner loop as follows:

```
  # iterate over array contents
  for ((i=0; i<${#ARRAY[@]}; i+=25)); do
    printf '%s\n' \
      "structure peg${ARRAY[$i]}" \
      '  number 1' \
      '  inside cube -$d. -$d. -$d. $d.' \
      'end structure'
  done
```

---

Points to note:

- We're only doing a redirection **once**, for the whole block. Putting `>>output.inp` on a bunch of separate commands re-opens the file once each time, making it very inefficient.
- `{start..end..count}` syntax is quite limit (cannot use variables), so C-style for loop syntax is strongly preferable.

Comment: IMPO it would read better to actually use printf's interpolation features. *shrug*

Comment: @kojiro, *shrug*, indeed. A format string of `'%s\n'` allows fewer separate `printf` invocations, which is why I prefer it here.

Comment: When I write the loop inside the echo, it just print out as; 
for idx in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99; do
  printf '%s\n'     structure peg5      number 1     'inside cube -300. -300. -300. 300.'
done

Comment: @MuhammadSajidIqbal, if you look at what I demonstrate here, it **doesn't** embed a loop inside an echo; instead, it calls echo inside a loop (as does Cyrus's implementation as well). If you're going to comment on a suggested implementation, please actually try to follow its advice. :)

Comment: @MuhammadSajidIqbal, ...btw, I've edited to add a variant using a C-style `for` loop. Still, the larger difference in approach (embed the echo in the loop, not the loop in the echo) stands.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, The second solution works for me. Thank you a lot sir!